# Density of probability and Distribution function, how to turn one into the other

Tags: probability-distributions

I know that to know the Distribution function I got to integrate the Density function from "-oo" to "x", but how to do the inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: can you even tell me why I got to integrate from -oo to x in the first case?

Comment: The integral gives you the area under the density curve, from $-\infty$ to $x$. Another way of thinking about pprobability densities is that you have a "wire" of variable density, of total mass $1$. You are trying to find the mass of the wire from $-\infty$ to $x$. So you divide the wire into very small bits of length "$dt$". The weight of the piece of length $dt$, from $t$ to $t+dt$, is about $f(t)\,dt$. To find the total mass, you "add up" (in reality, integrate).